# jstree link are not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am using following piece of code:

```
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>TODO supply a title</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.jstree.com/3.1.1/assets/dist/themes/default/style.min.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>HTML demo</h1>

            <div id="tree" class="demo">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
                                    <ul>
                                            <li><a href="https://mail.google.com">Gmail</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                            </li>
                           <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a>
                                    <ul>
                                            <li><a href="https://mail.yahoo.com/">yahoo mail</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                            </li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
    <script src="http://static.jstree.com/3.1.1/assets/dist/libs/jquery.js"></script>
          <script src="http://static.jstree.com/3.1.1/assets/dist/jstree.min.js"></script>

                                        <script>
                $("#tree").jstree({
                    "plugins": ["core", "themes", "html_data", "search"]
                }).on("select_node.jstree", function(e, data) {
                    document.location = data.instance.get_node(data.node, true).children('a').attr('href');

                });
                                        </script> 

    </body>
    </html>
```

I wanna negate to the other pages on clinking a node of jstree. This code working fine with latest versions but not working in IE8.
What should i do to make it work correctly?

---

Plese run it on a server when you try it on IE8 then you will find what is problem .

---

Answer (score 0):

Try using `window.location` instead of `document.location`, as the latter is read-only in IE:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location

Comment: sorry @vakata but still not working on IE8 I am using WAMP server to run it.It working fine for firefox but not working in IE8. :(